# float.Parse no longer working in Unity (C#)

Tags: c#, parsing, unity-game-engine

I had a working project with the following lines of code

```
 public InputField mass;
 float val = float.Parse(mass.text);
```

Pretty straighforward, an user puts an ammount of mass and it gets parsed from text to float, this was working perfecitly fine days ago, I was even able to export the project several times, no issues whatsover.

Today I returned to make some changes, before doing so I test it out and get this error.

> FormatException: Invalid format. System.Double.Parse (System.String s,
>   NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Double.cs:209)
>   System.Single.Parse (System.String s) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Single.cs:183)
>   ControlMasa.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/ControlMasa.cs:47)

I have no idea why it suddendly stopped working, not as if I had updated the version of Unity or anything, one day it was working and the next it wasn't.

What's the problem, what can I do?

Comment: What is the value of `mass.text`?

Answer (score 4):

You are not assigning a FormatProvider, which may cause errors depending on your System. You could try

```
float var = float.Parse(mass.text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

given that mass.text will always be a valid float number. As you are dealing with Unity you might also want to try

```
float var = float.Parse(mass.text, new CultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat);
```

which will always parse the float in standard US format (with a dot).

However, there might also be other Problems in your code, e.g. maybe the string isnt always a parsable float, you might want to use TryParse instead or make sure it can always be parsed to a float representation.

Answer (score 0):

Given from your question

```
InputField mass = null; // assign this first
float mass_ = "0.1f" //sample value
if(float.TryParse(mass.text, out mass_))
{
    /// everything is ok
}
else
{
    /// something wrong. mass.text has incorrect float value
}
```

Try instead of `Parse` a `TryParse` function .

Comment: `TryParse` requires a float field to output to

Comment: @Immersive Thanks . Sorry about that.

Comment: Once 2018.3 comes out, we'll be able to use inline `out` declarations due to C# being updated to 7.0 internally.

Comment: I'm still on c#4.0 hahahaha