# float.parse gives strange result after upload to iPhone, not in editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a string (_rawJson) with the following data after Substring:

```
0.561
```

I am using the following code:

```
float moonIllumination = -1;

bool success = float.TryParse(_rawJson.Substring(1, 5), out moonIllumination);
if (success)
{
    Debug.LogWarning($"Converted '{_rawJson.Substring(1, 5)}' to {moonIllumination}.");
}
else
{
    Debug.LogWarning($"Attempted conversion of '{_rawJson.Substring(1, 5) ?? "<null>"}' failed.");
}
```

Response after uploading the app to my iPhone:

```
Attempted conversion of '0.561' failed.
```

Response when running in Unity-editor:

```
Converted '0.561' to 0.561.
```

Is there anyone that can give me a hint of why this happen?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50402808/float-parse-no-longer-working-in-unity-c) i think. Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941476/float-parse-fails-on-decimals-and-commas)

Comment: correct, it’s most likely a locale issue

Comment: Side note: when creating [mre] for questions make sure to use neutral names for variables. Using "rawJson" as a name may give some people impression that you are trying to parse JSON by string splitting - since it is as smart as constructing XML or SQL with string concatenation it may lead to poor reception of the question. In this case no one cared... but good thing to keep in mind.

Comment: I agree, while it's a side issue, you really shouldn't parse JSON manually

Comment: First, a BIG thank you it made the trick => "float moonIllumination = float.Parse(_rawJson.Substring(1, 5), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);". Secondly, I do not parse a json! However I agree that the naming is not good.